# Apache Storm calling function from python bolt

Tags: python, apache-storm

I have a simple storm bolt which only needs to call a function from another python module. Everything works until I call a method which has print statements inside the function.

So my bolt:

```
import storm
from pipeline import module as m

class ExampleBolt(storm.BasicBolt): 

    def initialize(self, conf, context):
        self._conf = conf;
        self._context = context;
        storm.logInfo("ExampleBolt instance starting ...")

    def process(self, tuple):
        id, text = tuple.values
        result = m.dummy_funct(text)        
        storm.emit([result])         


ExampleBolt().run()
```

the method:

```
def dummy_funct(text):
    print "log info"
    return text
```

The bolt calls the method one time and then hangs on output. Using Apache Storm 0.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Check that, whether from second time only process block is getting executed.
 Not the whole program is getting executed.